I am trying to run my component tests on docker on windows OS, but it by default picks my tests from e2e
I am trying to run my vue3 component tests on docker, for which I have created below image.

image version: 10.5.0
cypress version: 13.7.3
OS: Windows 10

it runs my component tests from command prompt with below command:
npx cypress run --component
But, when I try to run through docker using file as seen above, it by default picks my e2e tests and runs instead of my component tests.(dockerfile command: CMD ["npm","run","npx cypress run --component"])
Please guide me.
I tried multiple attampts of creating images in docker, and also tried with changing versions.

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.  Can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve], in plain text?  Can you describe what command exactly you're running and what tests are or aren't running?

It worked with below dockerfile.. Have changed my command there..
Old docker command: CMD ["npm", "run", "npx cypress run --component"]//not working
New solution: CMD ["npm", "run", "npx cypress run", "--component"] //working
Docker file below works fine for me now. I can test my Vue3 component tests from Cypress in docker.

After adding this Dockerfile to Cypress root project, please execute below through terminal:

docker build -t ImageName . //ImageName is docker image name
docker run -it ImageName

